# Do you need to put something in your code to access an asset allowed by crossdomain.xml?

Tags: actionscript, flash, crossdomain.xml

Wondering if I need to do something in my swf to be able to access the assets on a different server, meaning more than just specify the url to the asset. Will flash handle the 'go get crossdomain.xml and authenticate everything' behind the scenes or do I need to include some special code beyond simply requesting the swf file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will flash handle the 'go get
>   crossdomain.xml and authenticate
>   everything' behind the scenes or do I
>   need to include some special code
>   beyond simply requesting the swf file?

In the event of any cross-domain request, Flash will look for the crossdomain.xml file at the root of the domain. For example, if you are requesting an XML file from:  `http://mysubdomain.mydomain.com/fu/bar/`

Flash will check if a crossdomain.xml file exist at: `http://mysubdomin.mydomain.com/crossdomain.xml`

If you ever need to load a crossdomain.xml file from a different location, you can do it via [Security.loadPolicyFile](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/system/Security.html#loadPolicyFile()) . Bear in mind that the location of this crossdomain have any impact on the security access you have.

You may also want to read up on the [security changes in Flash Player 10](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/fplayer9-10_security.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to access another swf, adding the crossdomain.xml will do all the work for you since Flash will do it for you